# Call an action method from layout in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have one layout and one partial view which are in the Shared folder. Partial view presents top menu items which are not static. So I need to call an action method to get menu items from database. To do this, I created a controller and add an action method in it.

When I try to browse the page in web browser, this error occured:

*The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.*

**Note:**
I tried Html.RenderAction, Html.Partial methods too...
And I tried to create another view folder, and create a new partial view and new controller that named with "folder name + Controller" suffix.

**Layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        @Html.Action("~/Views/Shared/_TopMenu.cshtml", "LayoutController", new {area =""}); //Here is the problem.

    </div>
   <div>
        @RenderBody();
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**_TopMenu.cshtml:**

```
@model IList<string>

@foreach (string item in Model)
{
    <span>item</span>
}
```

**LayoutController (in Controllers folder):**

```
 public class LayoutController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Shared/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        [ActionName("_TopMenu")]
        public ActionResult TopMenu()
        {
           IList<string> menuModel = GetFromDb();
           return PartialView("_TopMenu", menuModel);
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens if you put this in your view?

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("TopMenu", "Layout"); }
```

(And comment this out until everything works: //[ChildActionOnly])

Comment: So wrong thing is just a controller parameter using way? I remember that I used `Layout` too with `RenderAction`. But it did not worked. Maybe I have to sleep. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot get relax. I tried a lot of solution suggestions. Like your answer. Why it did not worked? Do you know reason?

Answer (score 4):

Change this line,

```
@Html.Action("~/Views/Shared/_TopMenu.cshtml", "LayoutController", new {area =""});
```

to,

```
@Html.Action("_TopMenu", "Layout", new {area =""});
```

and check.

Comment: I cannot belive it! Wrong thing is just a controller parameter using way. Thank you too.

Answer (score 2):

exist differents ways, for this case I like use html.action in layout, and in control I will create a string Menu,  the string contains the html code I need, the controller end with return Content(menu);

for example

Layout:

```
<body>
    <nav>
       @Html.Action("_TopMenu", "Layout")
    </nav>
```

the controller

```
   public class LayoutController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult _TopMenu()
        {
            IList<string> menuModel = GetFromDb();
            string menu = "<ul>";
            foreach(string x in menuModel)
            {
                menu +="<li><a href='"+x+"'>+x+"</a></li>";
            }
            menu+="</ul>";
            return Content(menu);
        }
   }
```

I like that because I can use many options to create menus dinamics more complexes.

other way use ajax to recovered the data and use handlebars or other template for the code

Comment: I have not heard handlebras before. It looks useful. I will play around with it. Thanks for the different way and the tool suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong overload of the Action-Method. The 2nd parameter in the variation is not the controllername but the actionname.

You can check the correct Method overloads on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx)

Also: If you specify Controllers in the Html.Action Method (which you can do for example with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457(v=vs.118).aspx) variation of the Method), you dont need to write the suffix "Controller" even if thats your Classname. So Instead of using the string "LayoutController" you would write simply "Layout".

At this point the framework is convention-based.

Comment: Do not worry about wrote answer rather than comment. You just want to help me. Robinson' answer deleted by Robinson. Because his answer was wrong by paramater count.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

**Layout**

```
@Html.Action("GetAdminMenu", "AdminMenu")
```

**Admin Menu Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult GetAdminMenu()
{
    var model = new AdminMenuViewModel();

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

**GetAdminMenu.cshtml**

```
@model ReportingPortal.Models.AdminMenuViewModel


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">School Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedID, new SelectList(Model.DataList, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedID), "", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "*" })
    </div>
</div>
```